# Why can I nest Styled Components but not ordinary React Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The following components render when I directly use Styled Components:

```
<Fragment>
    <Container>
        <Column>
        Works
        </Column>
    </Container>
</Fragment>
```

Where Container and Column are defined very simply as styled components in other files:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;

export const Column = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;
```

However, when I try to build more components the normal React way and nest them, they do not render on the screen.

So for example I define this column component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Column } from './Styles';

const column = () => {

  return (
  <Column>

  </Column>
  );
};

export default column;
```

Where column is defined in a styledComponent:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Column = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;
```

And this container component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Container } from './Styles';

const ContainerFlex = () => {

  return (
  <Container>

  </Container>
  );
};

export default ContainerFlex;
```

Where container is defined as a styledComponent:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Column = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;
```

But Column and it's text do not get rendered here, only container:

```
<Fragment>
    <Container>
        <Column>
        Works
        </Column>
    </Container>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `children` prop inside your custom component so that the enclose elements can be rendered.

The way you have defined your custom components they only render the `styled` component, not the enclosed children.

Solution,

***ContainerFlex component***

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Container } from './Styles';

const ContainerFlex = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <Container>
     {children}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ContainerFlex;
```

***ColumnFlex component***

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Column } from './Styles';

const ColumnFlex = ({children}) => {

  return (
    <Column>
     {children}
    </Column>
  );
};

export default ColumnFlex;
```

When you render your main component, the enclose elements will render now.

```
<Fragment>
    <Container>
        <Column>
         <p>Works</p>
        </Column>
    </Container>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `styled-components` are expecting "children", which mean you can nest each another.

At the end of the day, it is a styled **div** (`styled.div`) and `div` expecting children.

You can do this with React Components as well, however you need to explicitly render the children so they can be used as parent component. And then you will be able to nest those.

So, if you want to render:

```
<Fragment>
    <ContainerFlex >
        <column>
         <p>Works</p>
        </column>
    </ContainerFlex >
</Fragment>
```

You will need `ContainerFlex` to be able to render the children:

```
        <column>
         <p>Works</p>
        </column>
```

So, your component definition will be:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Container } from './Styles';

const ContainerFlex = (props) => {

  return (
  <Container>
     {props.children}
  </Container>
  );
};

export default ContainerFlex;
```

You'll have to do the same with `column` component, since it needs to render its children (which is `<p>Works</p>`):

```
import React from 'react';

import { Column } from './Styles';

const column = (props) => {

  return (
  <Column>
     {props.children}
  </Column>
  );
};

export default column;
```